# How to make this corousel slider clickable in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here is my code for corousel slider in Flutter, I want to make this slides clickable how can I do that?
When an image in corousel slider is clicked I want to open screen particular to the image category.

```
class _CarouselExampleState extends State<CarouselExample>  {
  List imgNews = [
    "images/groceries.jpg",
    "images/image_1.png",
    "images/photographer.jpg",
    "images/electrician.jpg",
  ];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  List<T> map<T>(List list, Function handler) {
    List<T> result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      result.add(handler(i, list[i]));
    }
    return result;
  }

  int _current = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            children: [
              CarouselSlider(
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  autoPlay: true,
                  height: 150,
                  viewportFraction: 1.0,
                  onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                    setState(() {
                      _current = index;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                items: imgNews.map(
                      (url) {
                    return Container(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ClipRRect(
                              child: Image.asset(
                                url,
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                height: 150,
                                width: 300,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                    );
                  },
                ).toList(),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:150),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: map<Widget>(imgNews, (index, url) {
                    return Container(
                      width: 6.0,
                      height: 8.0,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: _current == index ? Colors.red : Colors.blueGrey,
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ]
    );
  }
}
```

I tried many ways but I was not able to make this corousel_slider clickable, anyone please help, when an image is clicked i want to open screen particular to the image category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`InkWell`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) widget wrapped in `Material` -

```dart
child: Material(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            // Do something.
          },
        ),
      ),
```

In your specific case -

```dart
...
items: imgNews.map(
  (url) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        ClipRRect(
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                // Do something.
              },
              child: Image.asset(
                URL,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                height: 150,
                width: 300,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
 },
).toList(),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here is How you can do that

- First Make Carousel Image clickable

in your Case: Wrap it With GestureDetector

```
                    ClipRRect(
                              child: Image.asset(
                                url,
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                height: 150,
                                width: 300,
                              ),
                            ),
```

- Second Then on Tap of Image Get the **Image Index** and Pass it to A Function

```
                    onTap: () {
                                imgList.indexOf(url);
                                indexMethod(imgList.indexOf(url).toString());                             
                              },
```

- Last Create a Method

```
  indexMethod(String index) {
      switch (index) {
        case '0': 
          {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HelpPage()),
            );
          }
          break;
        case '1':
          {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UpdatesPage()),
            );
          }
          break;
        case '2':
          {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserProfile()),
            );
          }
          break;
      }
    }
```

> I Just Added This Functionality to My CarouselSlider :D